How does S3 handle deletions with AWS SDK delete_objects compared to individual delete_object calls?
I'm currently optimizing a data purging task in my application, which involves deleting multiple files stored in AWS S3. I understand that delete_objects can handle up to 1000 keys per request, which suggests that it might use batch processing to enhance performance.
However, I haven't found explicit documentation or proofs confirming whether delete_objects actually performs faster than individual delete_object calls for the same number of files. Specifically, I'm interested in understanding:

Whether delete_objects uses parallel processing or other efficiencies that significantly reduce the operation time compared to multiple single delete_object calls.
How the operation time might scale when deleting different numbers of keys (e.g., 100 vs. 1000 keys).

Does anyone have benchmarks, insights from AWS documentation, or personal experiences that could clarify how delete_objects optimizes these deletions?

it's really quite simple, if you have more than one object to delete at a time, call  DeleteObjects in batches of 1000.  That's why it exists.

The documentation is fairly clear: "this operation provides a suitable alternative to sending individual delete requests, reducing per-request overhead".  One API call instead of 1000 requires 999 less API calls, if nothing else.
